# Call to a member function getCacheTags() on null line 1630 of core/modules/views/src/Plugin/views/query/Sql.php

Tags: views, caching, 8

This error popped up a little while ago and we can't figure out what is causing it to be null or what needs to change. It is caused by a view that is set up as an rest api that you give it a NID.

Most NIDs work but random ones will not and instead throws this error.

Call to a member function getCacheTags() on null in Drupal\views\Plugin\views\query\Sql->getCacheTags() (line 1630 of core/modules/views/src/Plugin/views/query/Sql.php).
Drupal\views\Plugin\views\query\Sql->getCacheTags() (Line: 236)
Drupal\views\Plugin\views\cache\CachePluginBase->getCacheTags() (Line: 113)
Drupal\views\Plugin\views\cache\CachePluginBase->cacheSet('results') (Line: 1428)
Drupal\views\ViewExecutable->execute(NULL) (Line: 1451)
Drupal\views\ViewExecutable->render() (Line: 425)
Drupal\rest\Plugin\views\display\RestExport->execute() (Line: 1627)
Drupal\views\ViewExecutable->executeDisplay('rest_export_1', Array) (Line: 77)
Drupal\views\Element\View::preRenderViewElement(Array)
call_user_func(Array, Array) (Line: 378)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, 1) (Line: 195)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array, 1) (Line: 139)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->Drupal\Core\Render{closure}() (Line: 582)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 140)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->renderRoot(Array) (Line: 408)
Drupal\rest\Plugin\views\display\RestExport::buildResponse('story_referenced', 'rest_export_1', Array) (Line: 52)
Drupal\views\Routing\ViewPageController->handle('story_referenced', 'rest_export_1', Object)
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 123)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}() (Line: 582)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 124)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext(Array, Array) (Line: 97)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}()
call_user_func_array(Object, Array) (Line: 153)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 68)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 99)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 78)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 38)
Drupal\jsonapi\StackMiddleware\FormatSetter->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 48)
Asm89\Stack\Cors->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 50)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 657)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)

Comment: Do you mean that NIDs that do not exist throw this error?

Comment: Apparently I have a bad node. I found the node causing a problem, looking at the story it showed no body. But I went to edit and saved it again, then the story was working and the view rest just crashing.